# What is this strange C# class constructor syntax I've found?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I downloaded a demo by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) called 'PclPal' as found [here](https://github.com/jskeet/DemoCode/tree/master/PclPal) - it refuses to compile in Visual Studio 2013 due to some C# syntax I don't recognise.

Two of the .cs files appear to have constructor logic in the actually class declarations, like so:

```
 public class Profile(string path, IEnumerable<SupportedRuntime> runtimes)
    {
        public string Name { get; } = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        public String Path { get; } = path;
        public IReadOnlyCollection<SupportedRuntime> SupportedRuntimes { get; } = runtimes.ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

What is this?  Is this some future version of C# I've not yet learned?

**EDIT**: I don't see this as a duplicate question.  The linked question says 'Why don't primary constructors compile?', whereas this question effectively says 'What are [these things that turn out to be] primary constructors?'

Comment: This is allowed in C# 6

Comment: @EricJ. Well, it *will be*, when it's actually released officially.  Currently it's still in it's preview version.

Comment: @Servy: You can use it today, at your own risk :-)

Comment: It won't compile in VS2013, but if you download the RC for VS2015, it will compile.

Comment: Haven't primary constructors been canceled? https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820

Comment: Primary constructors were cut from C# 6

Comment: @Servy C#6 has a "go live" licence - it's supported. That said, primary constructors were cut AGES ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are features that were originally coming to C# 6, "Auto Properties with Initializers" and "Primary Constructors".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx